# Grid On Top Of A WINRT Media Element Causes Video To Be Blank

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a MediaElement full screen on a page.  On top of this I have a grid that contains controls (Play,Pause etc..) and general info about the video.  These controls are hidden after a few seconds of no user interaction.

If any part of the controls overlap the video being played then the entire Video is blanked out and only reappears when the controls grid is collapsed. Is it not possible to have a control of any kind over the top of a media element?

I notice that the "Video" App that comes as part of Windows8 RTM has this kind of effect over the top of a video that is playing.

UPDATE:
I've found the problem but not a solution.  I'm trying to have a "Global" mediaelement so I can view it on different pages (Fullscreen, preview etc).  I found this answer

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/241ba3b4-3e2a-4f9b-a704-87c7b1be7988

And followed Jim Man's suggestion to create a MediaElement on the root frame and then pull that item when needed. The issue happens as soon as I say CurrentPageMediaElement = RootFrameMediaElement

I presume it's changing the z order of the media element to that of the "Global" media element in the root frame? I'm not sure why it shows video when ControlsGrid is collapsed as the root grid is still there.  If I change the root grid to have an opacity less than 1 I see the media element all the time as in the code below.

If someone has a better way to share a Global Media Element around then that would also work.

```
//Here I Can't See The MediaElement
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" Background="Black">
    <MediaElement x:Name="MainMediaElement" />
    <Grid x:Name="ControlsGrid" Opacity="0.7" />
</Grid>

//Here I Can See The Media Element
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" Background="Black" Opacity="0.7">
    <MediaElement x:Name="MainMediaElement" />
    <Grid x:Name="ControlsGrid" Opacity="0.7">
</Grid>
```

Comment: Not an answer really, but it could be related to this thread on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/01987639-9902-4291-86ee-f9e1a3e96df9/). The MediaElement is a bit buggy.

Comment: FWIW, the video app was written with Html5 and the Video tag or DirectX via a WinMd C++ wrapper rather than using the XAML MediaElement. That could explain why it works in the video app, but not in your C# attempt.